# soapAction attribute in soap:Operation Element in WSDL

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I was reading this wsdl file and i came across this binding element.

```
<binding name="FactorialServicePortBinding" type="tns:FactorialService"><soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/><operation name="calculateFactorial"><soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body use="literal"/></input><output><soap:body use="literal"/></output></operation></binding>
```

And i am wondering what is this **soapAction** attribute in **soap:operation** element.
Can anyone explain this attribute and it's usage ??
Thanks